# The definition of compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

One of the definitions of compact operator is so: the closing of the image of unit Ball is compact. Can we take a sphere instead of a Ball?

Comment: Assume $x_n$ are in the unit ball and $K$ maps the unit sphere to a relatively compact set. If infinitely many of the $x_n$ are zero, then the subsequence of their images converges. Assume only finitely many are zero, and remove the finitely many that are zero. Then $y_n=\|x_n\|^{-1}x_n$ are elements of the unit ball. Then $Ky_n$ has a convergent subsequence $y_{n_i}$. The sequence $\|x_{n_i}\|\in [0,1]$ has a convergent subsequence $\|x_{n_{m_i}}\|$, since $[0,1]$ is compact. Then $Ky_{n_{m_i}}=\|x_{n_{m_i}}\|^{-1}Kx_{n_{m_i}}$ converges.

Comment: The other direction, assuming that $K$ maps the closed unit ball into a relatively compact set is clear and concluding that it maps the unit sphere to a relatively compact is clear by particularization.

Comment: @cmk and others: Careful with the English 'any', which can mean either 'all' or 'some'. In this case the characterization is with *all* bounded subsets. In particular, it is not a direct consequence of that characterization that requiring it for the unit sphere alone is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$, $W$ be normed vector spaces. Consider the map $\Phi:\Bbb R\times V\to V$, $\Phi(t,x)=tx$, let $T:W\to V$ be a linear map, let $S$ be the unit sphere (in $W$), let $E$ be the closed unit ball (in $W$) and let $B$ be the open unit ball (in $W$). Then, $T(E)=\Phi\left([0,1]\times T(S)\right)$. If $\overline{T(S)}$ is compact, then so are $[0,1]\times \overline{T(S)}$ and $\Phi\left([0,1]\times\overline{ T(S)}\right)$. It follows that $\Phi\left([0,1]\times\overline{ T(S)}\right)$ is closed and it contains $\Phi\left([0,1]\times T(S)\right)=T(E)$. Therefore $T(E)$ is relatively compact.

On the other hand, if $T(B)$ is relatively compact, then so are $T\left(\frac12 S\right)$ and $T(S)=2T\left(\frac12 S\right)$.